Vue 3 Print Component
I have a vue 3 app where I am dynamically creating a component (appdisplay). I want to print this component only (along with it's style and data). I had it working but all of a sudden it no longer works, with error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')". What might have changed or what am I missing now? Vue version is recently updated to 3.4.21. Am I not able to reference that component by id now?
Vue Template File
<script setup>
  import { ref, reactive, nextTick, toRaw, getCurrentInstance} from 'vue';
  import appdisplay from '@/components/appdisplay.vue';

  function printApp(){
      const prtHtml = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;

      let stylesHtml = '';
      for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
        stylesHtml += node.outerHTML;
      }
      const printer = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
      printer.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          ${stylesHtml}
        </head>
        <body>
          ${prtHtml}
        </body>
      </html>`);

      printer.document.close();
      printer.focus();
      printer.print();
      printer.close();

  }

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="printApp" >Print</v-btn>                

    <appdisplay id='print'></appdisplay>
  </div>
</template>


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's not evident that id='print' results in DOM element having id='print', its existence is not guaranteed. You shouldn't generally access DOM directly without a proper reason. Here you should have been using template ref instead

@EstusFlask If I use 'ref' instead, how might I be able to reference the innerHTML of ?

Like appdisplayRef.value.$el.innerHTML. It should be taken into account how appdisplay is implemented any way. It's unknown if there's a reason for it to not work as is

Unfortunately, that line does not work either.

Doesn't work in which way? See the previous comment, you need to provide a way to reproduce the problem. The question doesn't conform SO rules otherwise

The solution was to wrap the html inside the component with a 
